# Bootstrap scrollpy breaks on refresh when images are included

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, refresh, scrollspy

I am using bootstrap scrollspy in a site that I am building within a CMS system, and it currently doesn't sync up when I scroll when I refresh for one of my pages. It works perfectly  in a different page that doesn't have any images in it, but on the page that has a large amount of images it breaks. It doesn't work when housed outside the CMS system either. Because of the CMS system I have to use the data attributes to call the scrollspy.

I have tried many different things such as changing css and reorganizing the page, but it's always the same issue with the page that has images. Any ideas as to what could be causing the problem?

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What is "but on the page that has a large amount of images it breaks"? What is the error? Does the error comes from the server? Does the error comes from the client?

Comment: On the page with a large amount of images, the Scrollspy doesn't sync properly when the page is scrolled, and goes faster/jumps to the next section before I have actually scrolled there. I assume it is some issue with the CSS I have applied to the images. Is there a possibility that some sort of float, clear, or other CSS could mess with the height of what is being spied on? @Paco